# Why do my fields disappear after using lag()?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, lag

```
DA %>% group_by(BINS) %>%
  summarize(Lambda1 = sum(ACCEPTED), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(Lambda = lag(Lambda1)) %>% View
```

Why do ACCEPTED and other variables not mentioned disappear after I run this code?

I joined this data frame to the original to get those fields back but I'm still unsure why they were dropped.

Comment: When you use `summarize()`, the only columns that are retained are the columns defined within (such as `Lambda1`) plus any grouping columns.

Comment: Thank you for th clarification! @langtang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because only the group column and the summarized variables are kept when grouping and summarising variables.

Suppose you have columns (BINS, ACCEPTED, Col3).

```
  BINS ACCEPTED Col3
1    A        3    5
2    B        4    2
3    B        5    1
4    A        7    4
```

What your code is doing is grouping the BINS variables, sum all ACCEPTED values that are in each BINS

in this case

```
df %>%
  group_by(BINS ) %>%
  summarise(Lambda1 = sum(ACCEPTED), .groups = "drop")

  BINS  Lambda1
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A          10
2 B           9
```

if you want other variables to appear you need to provide their summary operation, i.g. meanCol3 = mean(Col3)
`.groups = "drop"` this simply means that your data frame is not grouped anymore.